# Moving an entity framework application and database

Tags: entity-framework

Being a little on the newer side of entity framework I am presented with problem that does not make alot of sense to me. I have to move an application which uses entity framework and the associated database from one domain/server to a seperate domain/server. After moving the application and restoring the database I proceeded to update the connection strings in the web config file. I now get an unhandled exception when the code tries to access a data table via Entity Framework but returns a null value. I feel like I might have missed a step when setting up the applicaiton in the new environment. Is there something I need to do outside of the web config file modiifications that will let the application know it is residing in a new environment.

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Probably you have entered invalid server name or user name in the web.config. You can try to create a EF Model from your local Visual Studio to the new server. Take all the information of the connection string and paste it to the web.config of the server. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution was a missing service account for not only the application pool identity but also as a valid user for the SQL Server Database. Once those two actions were done the application worked fine.